# contador dentro de una funcion de ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

Como puedo incluir un contador de registros para mostrar en mi tabla, tengo el siguiente esquema:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/registros',
    success: function(registros){
      let tbody = $('tbody');

      tbody.html('');
      registros.forEach(registro =>{
        tbody.append(`
          <tr>
            <td>aqui tiene que ir el contador por cada registro</td>
            <td id="cod_history">${registro.cod_history}</td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" class="name_person" value="${registro.name_person}"/>
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" class="specialty" value="${registro.specialty}"/>
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" class="office" value="${registro.office}"/>
            </td>
            <td>
              <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm retorn-button" type="submit">Confirmar Retorno</button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        `)
      })
    }
  })
```

Comment: forEach((registro, index) => { console.log("Numero: ", index); });

Answer (score 2):

La función forEach cuenta con un segundo argumento el cual corresponde al índice del elemento actual del arreglo que se está recorriendo, el cual podrías usar para mostrar el número de cada registro. Saludos.